# Developer's console does not show AppEngine under Compute menu

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a new AppEngine project a few days ago using the original AppEngine console.

When I view it in the new Google Developer's Console, the "COMPUTE" menu option only shows "Compute Engine" as an option.  Other older apps show both "App Engine" and "Compute Engine" as options.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to create the new project via console.developers.google.com, not via appengine.google.com. If you create the project using appengine.google.com, the App Engine menu will not appear.

Comment: gab06, what do you mean "create the new project via console". I already did this - that's how the "COMPUTE" menu appears on the left; it's within the project. Still don't see my appengine listed.

Comment: @erickCo I think [appengine.google.com](https://appengine.google.com) is the older site for creating GAE apps, and [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com) is the newer. Both lists all of your apps. But when you create an app using the older it doesn't get all the new features. So in order to get the App Engine submenu you need to use the new site.

Comment: @gab06 I created the project in developers console. After that you can click on the project name which shows a page that lists all the resources on the left of the page. One of the resources is called "COMPUTE". Click on that and it expands to show *only* "COMPUTE ENGINE". Now what?

Comment: @erickCo Ok, that's weird. I believe you will need to start a new question for that issue.

Comment: Confusingly the Compute option does show the App Engine menu for older projects, just not new projects created via the App Engine site. Thanks